# What is 'differential timing' technique for doing benchmarks?

Tags: benchmarking

At around 39 minute of "Writing Fast Code I" by Andrei Alexandrescu ([link here to youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrfYLlR8X8k&t=39m7s))

there is a slide of how to use differential timing... can someone show me some basic code with this approach? It was only mentioned for a second, but I think that's an interesting idea.

> - Run baseline 2n times (t<sub>2a</sub>)
>     vs. baseline n times + contender n times (t<sub>a+b</sub>).
> - Relative improvement = "t<sub>2a</sub> / (2t<sub>a+b</sub> - t<sub>2a</sub>)"
> - some overhead noises canceled

Comment: [WORKING LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrfYLlR8X8k&t=39m7s) As opposed to the OP I would be more interested in some mathematical reasoning behind the 2nd approach -- I think it's rather trivial to pour into code..

Answer (score 1):

Alexsandrescu's [slide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrfYLlR8X8k&t=39m7s) is rather trivial to pour into code:

```cpp
auto start = clock::now();
for( int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++ )
    baseline();
auto t2a = clock::now() - start;

start = clock::now();
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    baseline();
// *
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    contender();
auto taplusb = clock::now() - start;

double r = t2a / (2 * taplusb - t2a) // relative speedup
```

* Synchronization point which prevents optimization across the last two loops.

I would be more interested in the mathematical reasoning behind measuring the relative speed up this way as opposed to simply `tBaseline / tContender` as I've been doing for ever. He only vaguely hints at '...overhead noise (being) cancelled (out)', but doesn't explain it in detail.

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense to me from a low-level asm / CPU-microarchitecture POV, especially not if either or both of them are small enough functions that out-of-order execution can overlap their execution with each other, or the next iteration of itself.  If `baseline()` bottlenecks on division throughput, for example, and `contender()` avoids division, it might run effectively in the shadow of `baseline()` and barely increase the cycles/iteration vs. the first loop.  So you'd correctly calculate that `contender()` added near-zero time to that loop.  But you prob. want a different context.

Comment: @PeterCordes good point! Let me rewrite the 2nd measurement into two loops and let's assume we can insert some 'hacks' to prevent the compiler from optimizing across the two loops, i.e. the 2nd loop using a result produced by the 1st one..

Comment: You always need stuff to prevent optimization across loop iterations anyway; that's a common factor in all microbenchmarking.  e.g. a "dontoptimize" or "escape" macro using GNU C inline asm to make a compiler forget about the value of a variable, or just to force it to materialize something in a register.  Or more simply, just to sum the return values and print at the end.

Comment: After splitting, this seems even stranger.  Maybe there's some mathematical reason / benefit, but in terms of accounting for measurement overhead I'm not seeing it.  Maybe there's something that would make sense after someone pointed it out, but I can't see the benefit of running a different implementation which potentially dirties more cache (and evicts different cache lines), competes for more branch prediction entries, etc.  Although with large `n` that makes no diff when not alternating.  If it were timed separately, different alignment from another copy affects branch prediction?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep watching until 41:40 or so, he mentions it again when warning about the pitfall of first run vs. subsequent (allocators warmed up, etc.)

The best solution for that is doing warm-up runs before the first timed region.

**I think he's picturing that `2n` baseline vs. `n` baseline + `n` contender in *separate* invocations of the benchmark program.**

So instead of doing some warmup runs *before* the timed region, **he's using the baseline *as a controlled warmup* inside the timed region**.  This might make it possible to just time the whole program, e.g. `perf stat`, instead of calling a time function inside the program.  Depending on how much process startup overhead your OS has vs. how long you make your repeat loop.

---

Microbenchmarking is *hard* and there are many pitfalls.  Notably benchmarking optimized code while still making sure there isn't optimization between iterations of your repeat loop.  (Often it's useful to use inline asm "escape" macros to force the compiler to materialize a value in an integer register, and/or to forget about the value of a variable to defeat CSE.  Sometimes it's sufficient to just add the final result of each iteration to a sum that you print at the end.)

**This is the first I've heard of this differential idea.  It doesn't sound more useful than normal warm-ups.**

If anything it will make the contender look slightly worse than using the function under test for some warm-up runs before the timed region.  Using the same function as the timed region will warm up branch-prediction for it.  Or not because after inlining the warm-up vs. main versions will be at different addresses.  The same pattern at different addresses may possibly still help a modern TAGE predictor but IDK.

Or if `contender` has any lookup tables, those will become hot in cache from the warmup.

In any case, warmups are essential, unless you make the repeat count long enough to dwarf the time it takes for the CPU to switch to max turbo and so on.  And to page-fault in all the memory you touch.

If your calculated time/iteration doesn't stay constant with your repeat count, your microbenchmark is broken.

---

**Take the rest of his advice with a grain of salt, too**.  Most of it use useful (e.g. prefer 32-bit integers even for local temporaries, not just for arrays for cache-footprint reasons), but the reasoning is wrong for some of them.

His explanation that an ALU can do 2x 32-bit adds or 1x 64-bit add only applies to SIMD: 4x 32-bit int in a vector for `paddd` or 2x 64-bit int in a vector for `paddq`.  But x86 scalar `add r32, r32` has the same throughput as `add r64,r64`.  I don't think it was true even on Pentium 4 (Nocona) despite P4 having funky double-pumped ALUs with 0.5 cycle latency for `add`.  At least before Prescott/Nocona which introduced 64-bit support.

Using 32-bit unsigned integers on x86-64 can stop the compiler from optimizing to pointer increments if it wants to.  It has to maintain correctness in case of 32-bit wraparound of a variable before array indexing.

Using 16-bit or 8-bit locals to match the data in an array can sometimes help auto-vectorization, IIRC.  Gcc/clang sometimes make really braindead code that unpacks to 32-bit and then re-packs down to 8-bit elements, when processing an array of `int8_t` or `uint8_t`.  I forget if I've every actually worked around that by using narrow locals, though.  C default integer promotions bring most expressions back up to 32-bit.

---

Also, at https://youtu.be/vrfYLlR8X8k?t=3498, he claims that FP->int is expensive.  That's never been true on x86-64: FP math uses SSE/SSE2 which has an instruction that does truncating conversion.  FP->int *used* to be slow in the bad old days of x87 math, where you had to change the FP rounding mode, `fistp`, then change it back, to get C truncation semantics.  But SSE includes `cvttsd2si` exactly for that common case.

He also says `float` is no faster than `double`.  That's true for scalar (other than div/sqrt), but if your code can auto-vectorize then you get twice as much work done per instruction and the instructions have the same throughput.  (Twice as many elements fit in a SIMD vector.)

---

#### How the math works:

It just cancels out the `n` * baseline time from both parts, effectively doing `(2 * baseline) / (2*contender)` = baseline/contender.

It assumes that the times add normally (not overlapping computation).  `t_2a` = 2 * baseline, and `2 * t_ab` = 2 * baseline + 2 * contender.  Subtracting cancels the 2*baseline parts, **leaving you with 2*contender.**

The trick isn't in the math, **if anything this is more mathematically dangerous because subtracting two larger numbers accumulates error**.  i.e. if the `n*baseline` actually takes different amounts of time in the two runs (because you didn't control that perfectly), then it doesn't cancel and contributes error to your estimate.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure as Alexsandrescu deosn't go into much detail. However, I believe the issue is deeper than just warmup. The formula he shows looks like something you'd see in statistics -- I'm sure a mathematician could prove how the 2nd formula has lower variance than the 1st..

Comment: @denniskb: hardly.  It just cancels out the `n` * baseline time from both parts, effectively doing `(2 * baseline) / (2*contender)` = baseline/contender.  It assumes that the times add normally (not overlapping computation).  `t_2a` = 2 * baseline, and `2 * t_ab` = 2 * baseline + 2 * contender.  Subtracting cancels the 2*baseline parts, leaving you with 2*contender.